# How can I create a function that performs multiple composition?

Tags: javascript, function-composition

I wanted to combine two or more functions to produce a new function.

How can I create a function that performs left-to-right function compositions by returning a function that accepts one argument?

For example:

```
const square = v => v * v;
const double = v => v * 2;
const addOne = v => v + 1;

const cal = myFunction(square, double, addOne);
cal(2) // 9; addOne(double(square(2)))
```

Comment: Will you please edit your question to show what you have tried so far?

Comment: not exact duplicate, but see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36273977/are-currying-and-composition-the-same-concept-in-javascript for reference

Comment: Did you consider using https://ramdajs.com/docs/#compose ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript function composition from 3 functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41590061/javascript-function-composition-from-3-functions)

Comment: @webNeat is it possible to do it without importing libraries?

Comment: Of course it's possible without library, you can simply look at the source code and learn from it https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/master/source/compose.js

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might have `myFunction` turn the passed functions into an array with rest parameters, and then return a function that iterates over the array with `reduce`, passing in the passed argument as the initial value:

```js
const myFunction = (...fns) => arg => fns.reduce(
  (a, fn) => fn(a),
  arg
);

const square = v => v * v;
const double = v => v * 2;
const addOne = v => v + 1;

const cal = myFunction(square, double, addOne);
console.log(cal(2)) // 9; addOne(double(square(2)))
```

Comment: cool! works like a charm to me! I further shorten it into `const myFunction = (...fns) => arg => fns.reduce((a, fn) => fn(a), arg);` Thanks!